# Insert multiple rows into a table with a single statement

Tags: sql, database, insert

Looking to insert 500 rows into many-to-many table (sample_tag).

Aiming to have 500 new records created in `sample_tag` linking the first 500 rows from `sample` to associated `tag_id` in the `tag` table.

The following code seems to make sense, but triggers an error because the nested `SELECT` statement returns more than one row:

```
INSERT INTO sample_tag (sample_id, tag_id) 
VALUES ((SELECT sample_id FROM sample WHERE sample_id <= 500), 1)
```

What could be the correct SQL to accomplish this insert for multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple inserts by not using `VALUES` keyword. You need to specify same number of columns on your source table.

```
INSERT INTO sample_tag (sample_id, tag_id) 
SELECT sample_id, tag_id from sample where sample_id<=500
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  Works like a charm.  "tag_id" is in a separate table,  but was able to modify the code to 

INSERT INTO sample_tag (sample_id, tag_id) 
SELECT sample_id, "1" from sample where sample_id<=500